# Using Python's requests library instead of cURL

Tags: python, api, curl, instagram, python-requests

I 'm making a POST request in an attempt to gain an API access token. I'm using Python and the example I've been given from the documentation uses the cURL library as follows...

```
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

I'm using the Python request library and have written the following...

```
data =

{'client_id':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'client_secret':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'grant_type':'authorization_code', 
'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:14080/newpage', 
'code':code}        

token_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'
p = requests.post(token_url, params = data)
```

The URL does not give me access, what I am wondering is how is what I've written different to the documentation example. I am new to Python (and programming) so help is much appreciated.

Comment: The library is called `requests`, not `Request`, and the tag you've attached is the wrong one. (I'll fix that.)

Comment: woops, sorry about that

Comment: First, please show the exact results, not just "does not give me access". Meanwhile, one common reason people have this problem is unnecessary escaping. Without seeing your actual strings, it's very hard to tell if that's the problem here.

Comment: But _you_ can tell if that's the problem by making `curl` and `requests` both send to a local server that you control, and seeing what you get. The easiest way to do this is to run `nc -kl 8123` (that's for platforms with BSD netcat, like Macs), and change the URL to `http://localhost:8123/oauth/access_token`. Just look at what `nc` prints out in each case, and what's different between the two.

Comment: Wait a sec, I think I know the problem. Let me write an answer, and if I'm wrong, let me know…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending `params`, not `data`:

```
p = requests.post(token_url, params = data)
```

When you pass a dictionary as a `params` argument, `requests` tries to send it as part of the query string on the URL.

When you pass a dictionary as a `data` argument, `requests` will form-encode it and send it as the POST data, which is the equivalent to what curl's `-F` does.

You can verify this by looking at the request URL. If `print(p.url)` shows something like `http://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&…`, that means your parameters ended up on the URL instead of in the post data.

See [Putting Parameters in URLs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) and 
[More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) in the quick-start documentation for full details.

---

For more complicated debugging, you may want to consider pointing both `curl` and `requests` at a local server that logs everything, and compare and contrast what each client sends. A very simple quick&dirty way to do this is with [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat):

- In a terminal/DOS window, run `nc -kl 8123`. (The actual arguments differ slightly based on which netcat your platform comes with—or, if your platform doesn't come with anything, like Windows, which one you choose to install.)
- Run your `curl` command, but with `http://localhost:8123/oauth/access_token` as the URL.
- Run your `requests` script, again with `http://localhost:8123/oauth/access_token` as the URL.

Comment: Yep, you are right! p.url gave me a url structure incorporating the data parameters. Thanks. I'll check out nc -kl 8123.